tcpdump/wireshark aren't seeing DNS requests from browser or ping on Mac OS
I use Mac OS Sequoia 15.0.1 and I'm trying to capture DNS traffic using wireshark or tcpdump, but I can't see any packets whatsoever and I don't understand what Mac does differently here and why I can't observe this traffic.
Initially I thought that the browsers used DoH or some kind of proxy even after making sure they're disabled (Firefox/Chrome), but then I realised that pinging a domain also doesn't result in any traffic being captured.
I've also tested this on an older Mac OS (13.6.9) and it seems to be behaving identically.
sudo tcpdump -i any -n port 53 -nnp
ping aol.com

If I try using dig or nslookup, it works as expected. So it's clear to me that the browsers and ping use a different DNS path.
Any ideas why this happens and how the DNS requests are being sent?
What I also did was to make sure that "Private Wi-Fi Address" in the Wi-Fi section was turned off. At some point while doing this I also came across a request to "aol.com" in the packet capture, but I can't tell for sure what happened and it's quite hard to reproduce.
When I turn the Wi-Fi adapter off and on completely, all of a sudden I see all these DNS requests which correspond to my open browser tabs. So in that intermediary phase it seems to work as expected (i.e. I see the DNS traffic).
It might be the case that Apple actually simply ignores the user and does what it wants and still sends DNS requests over HTTPS to their server, but only when it makes sure that the DNS server is reachable (or something like that), but I can't be 100% sure of that.
[Later edit]
I've realised that when I set IPv6 to Link-Local Only, all of a sudden I can see all the DNS traffic.
This also applies when Mac OS sometimes decides to turn off IPv6 completely and arbitrarily when reconnecting/waking the laptop from sleeping, and I can see that it's set to "off" in the Wi-Fi Network settings (an option I normally don't have access to on the interface, i.e. I cannot manually set it back to "off").
[Update]
Another funny thing that I've noticed is that it isn't strictly about setting IPv6 to "Automatically". It seems to also be related to whether I get an IPv6 configuration (IP, Prefix, GW, etc.) or not.
On another Wi-Fi Network where IPv6 is not configured at all, I can see all the DNS traffic using tcpdump, even if it's set to "Automatically".

Are you certain those apps are using those ports to resolve names? I expect modern browsers to have more nuanced setups, results to be cached locally, and you’ll need to examine all traffic. Is this perhaps an XY question where you’re hoping to do something and DNS is your lever or first step?

Well, your question is partially part of my question. "These apps" are just Firefox/Chrome and ping itself. And "nuanced" setups, well, these are relatively well known. On Fedora I can see exactly how Firefox sends DNS requests, there's no issues with that.
On top of that, I did say that I can see the requests when I reconnect to the network, it's like a sort of leak.

Good catch with IPv4 and IPv6 management. Also, do the apps (wire shark and terminal app of choice) you use show up as being granted local network permissions? https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-your-local-network-on-mac-mchla4f49138/mac

It won't sent DNS queries for anything it's already looked up and cached the results for. You can clear the system resolver's cache with sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder (see this and this). Note that some programs (mostly browsers) may do their own lookups (and have their own caches) rather than using the system resolver.

Caching is not the problem. I've made sure to query completely new domains. Moreoever, as I've added later, tcpdump works consistently when turning off IPv6.
(the browsers are set to not use DoH or a DNS proxy or whatever)

@bmike Only now have I seen your comment. Yes, iterm2 has access to the local network (I asked a question related to that a few days ago and it's got solved. I also immediately thought of that afterwards. It doesn't seem to affect it in any way)
